# What are the consequences to breaking the ISS?

Tags: iss, liability

Suppose a relatively minor space faring government or a private company had permission to dock with the International space station. But then, due to their incompetence they caused a major problem. For example, suppose their vehicle malfunctioned while docked, thrusting the ISS into a spin and burning out the ISS reaction wheels. Now the ISS is permanently spinning too fast for anyone to dock and repair the damage.

In a case like this, who picks up the tab? What if those responsible cannot or will not pay? Are there international laws regarding liability and use of the ISS? Is a scenario along these lines a possibility?

Comment: If the ISS is permanently spinning too fast for anyone to dock, what about the astronauts inhabiting the ISS and their docked Soyuz capsules needed for return to Earth?

Comment: Some good answers by [@spacelawyer](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/25876/spacelawyer)